# Comparision of two sets of rank correlation coefficients from two samples

Tags: spearman-rho

How would I compare two sets of spearman correlation coefficients?

I have two sets of Spearman correlation coefficients, which I calculated on two different datasets with international trade data. For both samples the Spearman correlation coefficients are calculated for the two variables X (Gross exports), Y (GDP in trade). My goal of comaparing the rank correlation cofficients is to assess the similarity of the results from one dataset with the  the results from the second data set.

The first sample includes 860 observations (43 countries and 20 industries), and the second sample includes 1435 (41 countries and 35 industries). The samples overlap for 35 countries and 17 industries.